# What's the best way to escape from Ruby's TCPSocket::gets after a given timeout?

Tags: ruby, tcpsocket

I have following (simplified) ruby code, which opens ruby's TCP-Socket and reads from it:

```rb
socket = TCPSocket.open(server, port)

while line = socket.gets
  line = line.chop
end
```

Now I want read from the socket just for a given period of time (i.e. 1 minute). So after 1 one minute, the while block should be breaked and the process should exit.
Putting a line like

```rb
break if (elapsed_time > 1000)
```

into the `gets`-block is not possible, because if nothing is written to the socket, this line of code is not reached.

Comment: In Ruby 3.2 you can set `socket.timeout = 60` which will raise a `IO::Timeout` exception if `gets` exceeds 60 seconds. Instead of a fixed value, you might want to calculate the remaining time in your loop and update `timeout` before each `gets` call.

Comment: Alternatively use [`read_nonblock`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock) along with [`IO.select`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/IO.html#method-c-select) (the latter has an optional timeout argument). However that will return _bytes_ so you have to extract each _line_ yourself.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. Unfortunately I'm on ruby 2.7.6 at this app. Do you have a short example using `read_nonblock` along with `IO.select`?

Answer (score 2):

To read from an IO in a non-blocking way, there's [`read_nonblock`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/IO.html#method-i-read_nonblock). It either reads the available bytes (up to a given maximum) or raise an exception if the IO isn't ready for reading. Upon rescuing the exception, you can call [`IO.select`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/IO.html#method-c-select) to wait for the IO to become ready for reading.

`IO.select` takes up to 3 arrays with IOs to be monitored for 1) reading, 2) writing and 3) exceptions (you can monitor many IOs at once). A basic loop could look like this:

```
buffer = String.new

loop do
  begin
    buffer << socket.read_nonblock(1024)
  rescue IO::WaitReadable
    IO.select([socket])
  end
end
```

The above attempts to reads up to 1024 bytes which will be appended to `buffer`. If the read succeeds, it will read the next 1024 bytes and so on. If a read fails because the socket doesn't have any data, it calls `IO.select` which monitors the socket and returns as soon as more data is available.

`IO.select` also takes a 4th argument `timeout`. If the given value (in seconds) is exceeded, it will return `nil` which can be used to `break` the loop conditionally:

```
loop do
  begin
    buffer << socket.read_nonblock(1024)
  rescue IO::WaitReadable
    break unless IO.select([socket], nil, nil, 10)
  end
end
```

The above will wait up to 10 seconds for more data to become available or break the loop otherwise.

However, it will wait for 10 seconds per (failed) read attempt. To get a "global" timeout for the whole loop you might need something along these lines:

```
timeout = 10
buffer = String.new

t = Time.now
remaining = timeout

while remaining > 0
  begin
    buffer << socket.read_nonblock(1024)
  rescue IO::WaitReadable
    break unless IO.select([socket], nil, nil, remaining)
  end

  elapsed = Time.now - t
  remaining = timeout - elapsed
end
```

The above keeps track of the remaining time (in seconds) and passed that value as a timeout to `IO.select`.

Finally, you might want to process the lines as soon as they become available. To do so you could check the string buffer for a newline character and extract the line via [`slice!`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/String.html#method-i-slice-21) (possibly in a loop since you might have read multiple lines at once). Each extracted line could then be yielded:

```
def gets_while(io, timeout)
  buffer = String.new
  
  t = Time.now
  remaining = timeout
  
  while remaining > 0
    begin
      buffer << io.read_nonblock(1024)
      while (newline = buffer.index("\n"))
        yield buffer.slice!(0..newline)
      end
    rescue IO::WaitReadable
      break unless IO.select([io], nil, nil, remaining)
    rescue EOFError
      break # end of stream / connection closed
    end
  
    elapsed = Time.now - t
    remaining = timeout - elapsed
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
socket = TCPSocket.open(server, port)

gets_while(socket, 60) do |line|
  l = line.chomp
  # ...
end
```